# How to get a specific HTML element based on data-attribute (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple `<td`> elements with the data attribute `cell-pos`, set to different values, as per code below:

```
  setUpGrid($gameArea) { 
    for (let rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < this.board.gridSize; rowIdx++) { 
      const $tr = $("<tr>");
      $gameArea.append($tr); 
      for (let colIdx = 0; colIdx < this.board.gridSize; colIdx++) { 
        const $td = $("<td>");
        $td.data("cell-pos", [rowIdx, colIdx]);
        $tr.append($td);
      }
    }
  }
```

If I would like to retrieve a `<td>` element with a cell-pos value of [10,10], how would I go about doing this? I know with `.attr()` I am able to just use the selector `$('td[data-cell-pos="[10,10]"]')` but here I set the data attributes using `.data()` as I do not want to expose the data attributes values on the HTML mark up directly (which is what `.attr()` does)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is to find all the matching elements and then filter on their `cell-pos` data value being the same. For example (using a couple of `divs`):

```js
$('#div1').data('cell-pos', [5, 4]);
$('#div2').data('cell-pos', [4, 5]);

console.log($('div').filter(function() {
  let cellpos = $(this).data('cell-pos');
  return JSON.stringify(cellpos) === JSON.stringify([4, 5]);
}).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Note that using `JSON.stringify()` to compare will work for a simple array such as you have described, but you might need to rework the comparison code if your data value gets more complex.